# How to export data from sql server 2008 to excel and email as attachement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new. Can anyone advise how I can export data from database sql 2008 to excel and email as attachment?

Comment: Do you have to automate and schedule it?  
Have you tried using SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) - a Data Flow with an Excel destination, then a Send Mail Task.

Comment: Blaz, you should probably make than an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Simple example:

1. Control Flow task 1 - Data Flow:

   - OLEDB Source. Choose the source table/view/use a query...
   - Excel destination.
2. Control Flow task 2 - Send Mail Task. Attach the above generated Excel.

You can build the "Export from SQL to Excel" part also via the [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052%28v=sql.100%29.Aspx) in [BIDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174181%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Check [this video](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff686858.aspx) for a demo.
For the Send Mail Task, check this [BOL article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142165%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

If you want to automate and schedule it, you can use a [SQL Agent scheduled job with an SSIS job step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141701%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). A video demo is available [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440761%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).
If you automate it on a server, make sure [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) is installed (you do not need Excel there, just the "drivers").

Comment: Thank you Blaz, I will try your recommendation and see how I go about. My first time learning.